# Random image creating script trouble

Tags: php, image, random, forum

I have created a script which takes a random *IMAGE ID* from the database, converts it to a valid file name and then I use it to generate random images from a link.

This is how such a link looks like (works - try it):
http://imgit.org/roll.php?image=3J9N0Y4k8g4l4G7

When you reload that link, you'll notice the image changes. If I add this image to `<img src="THAT LINK" />` it works, however, it doesn't work on message board like phpBB or vBulletin when I put that link inside `[img][/img]` BBCode tags.

I suppose there is a problem with my script, because there are various services out there that do exactly the same thing (link on forums) and it works.

Here is my roll.php script:

```
<?php

$imgit_root_path = '.';
include("{$imgit_root_path}/common.php");

if ($config['disable_roll'])
{
    redirect('index.php');  
}

$roll_key = request_var('image', '');
$roll_key = substr($roll_key, 0, 15);

if (!$roll_key)
{
    redirect('index.php?action=404');   
}

if (!$image->roll_key_exists($roll_key))
{
    redirect('index.php?action=404');   
}

$images = $image->roll_info($roll_key);
$images = explode('|', $images);

$count = sizeof($images);
$index = mt_rand(0, $count - 1);

$extList = array();
$extList['gif']  = 'image/gif';
$extList['jpg']  = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['jpeg'] = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['png']  = 'image/png';

$image_url  = generate_site_url() . IMAGES_PATH . $image->get_name($images[$index]);
$image_inf  = pathinfo($image_url);

header('Content-type: ' . $extList[$image_inf['extension']]);
readfile($image_url);
?>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of such services, preferably with a link to an image like the one in your question.

Comment: @NabilKadimi I will try to find one, but it's kinda hard because they are rare.

Comment: I just pasted link to image on my forum as a test and everything worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem may be that phpBB will disallow links which aren't confirmed as images. That is, don't have a known image extension, such as .jpg;

https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1285255

> For security reasons, images whose extensions cannot be confirmed
>   (such as in the first example) aren't allowed by BBCode. Instead of an
>   image, it's fully possible for someone to embed a JavaScript script,
>   or even worse, onto a page which could be a security risk to anyone
>   visiting the page, or possibly even the server.

This is most likely the same in vBulletin.

Seems you can override it in the forum settings maybe?

Alternatively, if you can change you script, so that you can append a ".jpg" extension to the end, then that may also work!

Comment: I made it so that I can have an extension in the end like this `http://imgit.org/roll.php?image=3J9N0Y4k8g4l4G7.jpg` but it still doesn't work on phpBB. Any ideas?

Comment: As a test, can you try linking direct to a real picture using phpBB, just to make sure that works ok... If it does, we may need to look at mod_rewrite, to rewrite the url. It may be that because you have a .php in there, phpBB is blocking it... Also, do you know which version of phpBB is giving you problems?

Comment: I'm trying directly at phpbb.com/community and I thought about the .php extension - just did that and trying again now.

Comment: I've just registered at phpbb.com/community, and tried your link as my signature and it says "Your images may only be up to 60 pixels high" I wonder if his is throwing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is browser caches image. Try adding header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); before readfile($image_url);